# Jenkins fails to clone huge repo with early EOF

Tags: git, jenkins, git-clone

I have a repo with over 13gb stored, most of which is LFS. I'm not really sure this has to do something with LFS, but anyway.

The error is always the same.

```
Receiving objects:  96% (33831/35240), 43.64 MiB | 10.90 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  97% (34183/35240), 43.64 MiB | 10.90 MiB/s
Receiving objects:  98% (34536/35240), 43.64 MiB | 10.90 MiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

It always happens on the 7th second. The server is located in data center with a decent internet connection. It never fails to download already cloned branches, as well as some other branches, that weight a little bit less.

I have advanced clone enabled with shallow clone set to depth 1 and time limit increased to 30 seconds.

Jenkins is set up on Windows server.